# Dealing with potential duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently encountered a situation where someone's symptom was similar to the symptoms in another question. It's likely the cause was the same, but there is no way of knowing for sure without OP feedback. I made a comment in this situation suggesting the possibility and referencing the other question.

If I'd "answered" the question instead of commenting, I would have had rep potential and potentially could have saved other's time by not clicking through to an answered question, given the likelihood that the cause *was* the same. Any guidance here? Does SO have a preferred approach in this situation?

For reference, the question was/is [Factory not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330788/factory-not-registered#17331102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this where there is some doubt the correct approach is to comment linking to the duplicate and asking the OP if it's the same problem.

If they answer "yes" then vote to close as a duplicate.

If they answer "no" then remove the original comment and possibly replace it with one indicating it *might* be related.

If they don't answer move and and find something else to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that if you don't have CV privileges, you should flag as duplicate.